Shortcut for LyX Environment box
I usually use LyX environment box to choose section, definition, theorem, proof, etc.
At that time, I need to use mouse to click the LyX environment box.
However, I want to go to the LyX environment box by using keyboard.
Is there a way to do this?

Go to Tools → Preferences → Editing →  Shorcuts → Document and Window → Font, Layouts and TexClasess  →  Enjoy learning the default shortcuts or editing...
Example to use the shortcut for layout Section:

Write this in LyX:

    foo 
    bar


Put the cursor in the first line.

Press Alt + p  and 2. Result:



1 foo
bar

